# Cannot send email from Yii SwiftMail to GMail: Expected response code 250 but got code "535"

Tags: php, email, yii2, gmail

I got this error code:

> Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
>    535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257

However, I'm using TLS so how could it possible be more secure?!

There are a few other questions, but they are not for Yii.

Some code:

```
Yii::$app->mailer->setTransport([
  'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
  'host' => BestSales::getConfigValue('smtp.host'),
  'username' => BestSales::getConfigValue('smtp.username'),
  'password' => BestSales::decrypt(BestSales::getConfigValue('smtp.password.encrypted')),
  'port' => BestSales::getConfigValue('smtp.port'),
  'encryption' => BestSales::getConfigValue('smtp.encryption'), // 'tls', 'ssl'
]);
```

Values:

```
[
    'smtp.host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    'smtp.username' => 'contact@xxxxxxxxxx.com',
    'smtp.password.encrypted' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
    'smtp.port' => '587',
    'smtp.encryption' => 'tls',
]
```

I logged into Gmail and found this message:

> Sign-in attempt prevented
>   Hi BestSales,
>   Someone just tried to sign in to your Google Account contact@xxxxxxxx.com from an app that doesn't meet modern security standards.
>   Details:
>   Tuesday, 17 May 2016 23:27 (Eastern Daylight Time)
>   Ashburn, VA, USA*
>   We strongly recommend that you use a secure app, like Gmail, to access your account. All apps made by Google meet these security standards. Using a less secure app, on the other hand, could leave your account vulnerable. Learn more.
>
> Google stopped this sign-in attempt, but you should review your recently used devices

The Yii docs says 'tls' is an option. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-swiftmailer-mailer.html

Yes, I verified the decrypted value is the correct password. I've already visited https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha. I can't turn on 2-factor because I don't own the account and it needs a phone number. I can't turn on 'allow insecure access' right now as it's a client's account, but I've asked. (I'd rather not allow insecure access though.)

Answer (score 2):

```
   1. Enable the 2-step verification
   2. Create App Passwdord to be use by your system HERE and use it 
   3. Now go to .env file and make these changes
        
        MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
        MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
        MAIL_PORT=587
        MAIL_USERNAME=youremail@gmail.com
        MAIL_PASSWORD=password generated from app password
        MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
        
        This worked fine on mine.

    For 2-step verification 
       https://www.google.com/landing/2step/
    
    For App Password
       https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, use ssl in encryption and value 465 in port, because
of the two factor authentication do not use your gmail password, 
but create a gmail APP Password which is better to give access
from there to a less secure application, here is [the link](https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords) for
creating app passwords.

Answer (score 1):

Hey after couple hours of resarching have some tips to you:

1 - Enable less security app access on gmail

2 - Access this link : https://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

3 - on config/web.php add these params:

```
        'encryption' => 'tls', 
        'streamOptions' => [
        'ssl' => [
            'allow_self_signed' => true,
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: I think you SHOULD verify Google's SSL certificate, and it won't be self-signed either.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
'smtp.port' => '465',
'smtp.encryption' => 'ssl',
```

Comment: Sorry, it still failed with the same error message.

Answer (score -1):

You have to log into you gmail account and go the the security settings and notify them that it was you trying to access your account. They put a block on it because it looked suspicious.

Go to [this link](https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha) and try again.